# How to write dynamic where in LINQ

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I have a LinQ query as below

```
var filtered=from c in country
         where c.Id>=5
         select c;
```

Now i need to have the operator '>=' to be dynamic i.e., the operator may be '>=' or '==' or '<=' etc depending on a certain criteria and the query should execute based on that operator. How to achieve this in LinQ?

Comment: I'd rather write new methods or use a switch-case.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please? Saying that the operator changes based on a certain criteria it would be nice to know what that criteria is - user input, programmatic control, other queried data, etc. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Enigmativity: The criteria in my case is user selection. The user selects the different types of operators(>=,<=,==,!=) from a dropdown list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid the "if-then-else" or "switch" methods, and use a "dictionary" instead.

I assume you have a control that allows the user to select the number (ie 5) too, so you would need a way to "dynamically" add this to the query too.

Define this dictionary:

```
var filters = new Dictionary<string,
    Func<IQueryable<Country>, int, IQueryable<Country>>>()
{
    { ">", (cs, n) => cs.Where(c => c.Id > n) },
    { ">=", (cs, n) => cs.Where(c => c.Id >= n) },
    { "==", (cs, n) => cs.Where(c => c.Id == n) },
    { "<=", (cs, n) => cs.Where(c => c.Id <= n) },
    { "<", (cs, n) => cs.Where(c => c.Id < n) },
};
```

Now you can populate your drop-down with the keys from the dictionary and then you can easily get your query out by doing this:

```
country = filters[">"](country, 5);
```

Or maybe something like this:

```
country = filters[dd.Value](country, int.Parse(tb.Text));
```

Yell out if you'd like any further explanation.

Comment: it would be nice if you could accept this answe as your solution so others with the same problem can easily find it @Abilash

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins - it would be nice, wouldn't it... :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
var filtered = country.AsQueryable();
if(cond == 0)
    filtered = filtered.Where(c => c.Id <= 5);
else if(cond == 1)
    filtered = filtered.Where(c => c.Id >= 5);
else if(cond == 2)
    filtered = filtered.Where(c => c.Id == 5);
```

Comment: @downvoter: Without a comment, the downvote is not constructive

Comment: Depending on the type of 'country', this may not compile. In this case, 'filtered' should be explicitly declared IQueryable< >, rather than implicitly typed.

Comment: @devio - What do you mean that it may not compile? How will declaring it `IQueryable<>` be any better than implicitly typed?

Comment: @Enigmativity: implicitly typed means that the type of the variable is *the exact* type of that variable, e.g. `ObjectQuery<Country>`. But `Where` will return the more general type `IQueryable<Country>`. The assignment of an `IQueryable<Country>` to an `ObjectQuery<Country` is illegal. That's why `filtered` needs to be declared as `IQueryable<Country>`.

Comment: @Daniel - doesn't the `.AsQueryable()` ensure that it is `IQueryable<>`?

Comment: @Enigmativity: Exactly! That's why I added it after devio added his comment. It wasn't there before, see the history log.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** exactly what you want, however I think doing what you say is *not safe* and it is *bad for readibility* and *not reusable*.For those purposes I always try to use new methods and be `void` on them.

```
 public void static FilterById(int limit, string condition, IEnumerable filter, Type country)
 {  
    var countryQueryable = country.AsQueryable();//Edit inspired by devio's comment on  Mr.Hilgarth's answer. 

    switch(condition)
   {
      case(">") :
      {
        filter = countryQueryable .Where(q=>q.Id > 5)
        break;
       } 
       case(">=") :
       {
         filter = countryQueryable .Where(q=>q.Id >= 5)
         break;
        } 
        case("=") :
        {
          filter = countryQueryable .Where(q=>q.Id == 5)
          break;
         } 
        case("<=") :
        {
          filter = countryQueryable .Where(q=>q.Id <= 5)
          break;
         } 
         case("<") :
         {
          filter = countryQueryable .Where(q=>q.Id < 5)
          break;
         } 
     }
}
```

**EDIT:** [Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)  might help a bit.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth,@JohnnyCageWins: Thanks for the replies. I know to use an if..else or select..case for this scenario. I need to minimize the code by doing something else from the above mentioned techniques.So, is there any other possibilities?

Comment: I am going to add a link to my answer, however I really think what you want to do will make you suffer later. @Abilash